# I want to increase the row number the moment the value changes

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to increase the row number the moment the value changes. (in Amazon-Redshift)

I don't know what conditions to give the row_number.

row_number() over(order by id,timestamp) row_num

```
 id      ts   value    row_number
p051  |  ts | 20    |      1
p051  |  ts | 20    |      1
p051  |  ts | 20    |      1
p051  |  ts | 25    |      2
p051  |  ts | 20    |      3
p051  |  ts | 20    |      3
p051  |  ts | 30    |      4
p051  |  ts | 30    |      4
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just do  `library(data.table); rleid(df1$value)`

Comment: Wow .. amazing function .. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your request appears to assume an ordering, so I'll assume there is a column with ordering information, which I will assume is `timestamp`.

You can use `lag()` to get the previous value and then a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when value = prev_value then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id, timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (order by id, timestamp) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that this increments the values through the entire data.  Often, the purpose is to restart the numbering for each `id`.  In that case, use `(partition by id order by timestamp)` for the window specification.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.  However, the following error appears:
Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: I don't think my question was clear.
If a table is already aligned regardless of the group value, the purpose is to increase the row_number only by changing the column 'value' of the table.